# How to add custom framework to iOS Project from terminal/shell script

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins

I want to add my custom framework to my ios project from terminal /shell script.
I want to automate the process the way we used to add manually by drag and drop the framework to xcode build pahse.

Note : I don't want to use any third party tools like Cocoapods because of some restriction.

Is there any way to do so..
Thanks in advance . Kindly help

Comment: Read this -> https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: @dahiya_boy I know cocoapods but I don't want to use any third party tool due to some project restriction